# How to accept input from user (console) in erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm confused How can I accept input from the Erlang shell or eclipse console?
I want to accept input for the variable "input" from user.

```
p1()->
    io:format(" Codes for business logic of task one \n"),
    spawn(xorgateway, xor_split, []).
xor_split()->
 io:format("enter your decision \n").
   case Value of
         decision1 -> 
            spawn(xorgateway, p2, []);
        decision2 ->
            spawn(xorgateway, p3, []);
        decision3 ->
            spawn(xorgateway, p4, []);
          _->
            io:format("invalid input \n")end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm confused How can I accept input from the Erlang shell

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

    get_data() ->
        {ok, Term} = io:read("Enter a number: "),
        io:format("The number you entered plus one is: ~w~n", 
                  [Term + 1]).
```

In the shell:

```
8> c(my).        
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

9> my:get_data().
Enter a number: 10.
The number you entered plus one is: 11
ok

10>
```

Note that the user needs to enter a period after their input.  Also, see [io:getline()](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#get_line-1) and [io:fread()](https://erldocs.com/19.0/stdlib/io.html?i=0&search=io:fread#fread/2)

> I want to accept input for the variable "input"

`input` is not a variable in Erlang.  Erlang variables start with a capital letter.